# Comment when reputation is less than 50

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I know that for commenting on a certain question asked by some other person, one must have a minimum reputation of 50. Recently, while reviewing late answers, I came across a situation where a person without the privilege of writing comments wanted to ask something, and he wrote a comment in the answer section.

My question is what should be done in such a situation. Should he be allowed to ask something in answer, which I don't think should. Or should he wait and gain some reputation before he can post a comment.

Answer (score 6):

He (or she) should wait.

Flag such answers as not an answer:

[image]

Comment: (or _it_, don't discriminate against robots)

Comment: Robots are almost certainly spammers @Mat. I feel no sorrow for my robotist views :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Shouldn't that be anti-robotist?

Comment: i already did that.